# Actually complete re-tag requests

Tags: support, retag-request, synonym-request

I've just seen [Manishearth's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131480/help-us-close-completed-retag-requests-and-the-like) asking for completed re-tag requests on Meta to be closed.

I think it would be useful if uncompleted [re-tag requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request+-status-completed) (327) and [synonym requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request+-status-completed) (94) could either be completed or declined!

Obviously some will have already been done, maybe as part of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012 <sup>(shameless plug)</sup>.

Marking these completed requests as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) may be more useful than cleaning up those requests that already have them.

Comment: Yeah, what the heck are the moderators doing??! Why do they spend all their time deleting questions, instead of fulfilling these retag requests?

Comment: I know! Taken slightly out of context any statement can appear to be rude! Or, imply that moderators are lazy in this case. Mine and yours :-). I'm just seeing if there's an appetite to clean-up some requests rather than cleaning up some completed ones.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Lets all flag those questions for mod attention till they listen! ;-)

Comment: That's actually quite a good idea... do you think it would work :-)?

Comment: @Ben: It could_ work, but your flag weight may plummet due to aaaangry mods. ;-) If this meta post doesn't work, I guess we can do that... (or bounties)

Comment: I miss flag weight...